# Schedulers.boundedElastic() and Logging Issue

Tags: project-reactor

I have a very generic query as I'm using Schedulers.boundedElastic() in .subscribeOn in my reactive pipeline and I'm seeing a very strange problem of Logger not working as expected as it's messing with the reactive context like for example if I run a load test on the function, in the logger it's aggregating the latency on all. But if I use .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic()), Logger is working as expected

Let me post a skeleton of my code here for reference

```java
Mono.just(stream)
    .transform(#my application logic)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic())
        .subscriberContext(reactiveContext)
    .subscribe(
        s -> #logging happens here,
        error -> # error handling logic,
        () -> # inspect);
```

Comment: Could you give a [mcve] as to your specific problem? It's not too clear at the moment. Having said that, you might also want to try an async logger if you haven't already - especially during high load, a synchronous logger can add a surprising amount of overhead that could well upset things.